# How to improve CTE query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Is there anything I can do to speed up this query (using Postgres 9.3.4). I'm looking for the greatest version which is part of the directed graph (in this case version <= 300).

```
WITH RECURSIVE r(depth, revision_id) AS (
  SELECT count(1) AS depth, r.revision_id AS revision_id 
  FROM revision AS r 
  WHERE r.revision_id = 300 
  GROUP BY r.revision_id 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT rev1.depth + 1, rev2.parent_revision_id AS parent_revision_id 
  FROM rev1, revision AS rev2 
  WHERE rev2.revision_id != 1 AND rev2.revision_id = rev1.revision_id
)
SELECT t1.id AS id, t1.value as value
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.id) t2.id AS id, t2.rev_id AS rev_id 
  FROM product AS t2 
  WHERE t2.rev_id = (
    SELECT max(rev_id)
    FROM product
    WHERE t2.id = product.id 
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM r 
      WHERE r.revision_id = product.rev_id
    )
  ) AND t2.deleted = false 
) AS t1
```

I tried to select the max of the intersection of `select rev_id from product INTERSECT select revision_id from r`, but this is slightly slower than the `exists` version above. Also a temporary table in which I store the CTE didn't bring any improvements.

The above query with these records:

```
revision
--------
revision_id, parent_revision_id
1               null
2               1
3               2
4               2
5               3
6               5

product
-------
id, rev_id, value
1    2       a
2    3       b
3    4       c
1    5       a2
1    6       a3
...
    300      a256
```

results in

```
id, value
1   a256
2   b
```

(note `product.id=3` is not part of the result set as it is not a descendent of version 300)

Comment: Generally speaking - recursion is not the fast operation and has limitations, so performancewise in terms of extracting data, it might be better to pre-calculate what can be pre-calculated. You might also benefit from using temporary physical tables so you can create indexes on them for faster extraction - although be wary of the overhead of maintaining indexes. But given there's no real information about what, where and how much - it's difficult to give much other than general observations.

Comment: I must have forgotten to set up indices on the temp table. I can indeed measure a performance gain when an index is on `revision_id`  (at least for the select part, populating the temp table is costly). I could imagine using a normal (not temp) table as cache, but would need to combine it with the cte (as I can't ensure the cache being populated). Is this possible while still benefiting from the temp table's indices?